# Upgrading from GA.JS to Analytics.js - replacing _setDomainName, _addIgnoredRef & _trackEvent

Tags: google-analytics

I'm currently upgrading my company's website across to analytics.js from ga.js

As I understand, _setDomainName, _addIgnoredRef & _trackEvent are deprecated and need updating.

Can anyone confirm that the below is correct please?

```
gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'domain.net']);
```

This should be replaced with:

```
cookieDomain: 'domain.net',
legacyCookieDomain: 'domain.net'
```

---

```
_gaq.push( ['_addIgnoredRef', 'www.domain.com']);
```

This now has to be set in the Analytics admin section?

---

```
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Registration', 'New Account', '<organisation>']);
```

Should be replaced with:

```
ga('send', {
hitType: 'event',
eventCategory: ' Registration ',
eventAction: ''New Account ',
eventLabel: '<organisation>'
});
```

Any help would be gratefully received,

Thanks

---

How does this final example look?

```
<script>
    (function (i, s, o, g, r, a, m) {
        i['GoogleAnalyticsObject'] = r; i[r] = i[r] || function () {
            (i[r].q = i[r].q || []).push(arguments)
        }, i[r].l = 1 * new Date(); a = s.createElement(o),
        m = s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0]; a.async = 1; a.src = g; m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m)
    })(window, document, 'script', '//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js', 'ga');

    ga('create', 'UA-xxxxx', 'domain.net');
    ga('send', 'pageview');
    ga('send', {
        hitType: 'event',
        eventCategory: ' Registration ',
        eventAction: ''New Account ',
        eventLabel: '<organisation>'
     });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mostly right except for the cookie domain (at least it'S not obvious from your example that you got it right).

Cookie domain can either be passed as third parameter when you create your tracker:

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-Y', 'domain.com');
```

You can set the parameter to "auto" (IIRC that's the default) and the highest possible level in the domain will be selected as cookie domain (i.e. on subdomain.domain.com `auto` will set the cookie domain to domain.com).

You can also pass a configuration object with cookieDomain as a property:

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-Y', { 
'cookieDomain': 'domain.com'
});
```

which is a useful syntax if you want to set multiple settings at once (you  would pass each setting as key/value pair in the configuration object).

As you found out for yourself `_addIgnoredRef` is now replaced with the referral exclusion list, and your event tracking syntax is fine.

Comment: If that helped you might consider to "accept" the answer by clicking the check next to the answer (I get a few reputation points and the question is removed from the tab with the unanswered questions).

Comment: How does this final example look?

Comment: Looks good to me - this will send both a pageview and an event, provided the code is placed on the "domain.net" domain.